# unable to import new row to mysql pro database with laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm new to laravel and i'm trying to add a new row in my database but it is not working. 
The ultimate goal is to link it to my react native app so that every time a new user logs in, they get a unique token. For now just adding a new row with static data would be nice.

this is what I have in my routes: web.php:

```
Route::post('/posts/addnewdata', 'PostsController@create');
Route::get('/posts/printall', 'PostsController@index');
Route::get('/posts/{post}', 'PostsController@show');
```

and then in my controllers I have this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
use App\Post;
class PostsController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $allposts = Post::all();
        $allposts->toJson();
        return $allposts->toJson(JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }

    public function show($slug) 
    {
            $post = Post::where('title', $slug)->firstOrFail();
            $post->toJson();
            return $post->toJson(JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }

    public function create()
    {   
        $newData = array('id' => 6, 'title' => 'post-6', 'slug' => 'blog-6', 'body' => 'blog six in the database');
        Post::create($newData);

    }
}
```

when i type in the http://someurl/printall or the http://someurl/{some slug that is in my DB} it works, but the addnewdata gives a 404.

Comment: you are sending a `POST` request to `someurl/addnewdata`?

Comment: yes, as I said i'm new to this so I thought that I need to use POST to create new data and GET to retrieve data that already exists

Comment: i asked because you could also be sending a `GET` request to `someurl/addnewdata` which would hit the `show` method of that controller and then return a 404 because of the `firstOrFail` because it can't find a record with a title matching the slug `addnewdata`

Comment: So I just changed it to GET, and now when I also add the protected fillable [id, title, slug, body] in my post.php it works. I've been looking it up but I'm not really getting the logic behind it. Could you explain it?

Comment: changed what to a `GET` request? ... if you are sending a `GET` request you will not reach your `create` method

Comment: so first the route was Route::post('/posts/addnewdata', 'PostsController@create'), and I changed the POST in the route to GET and now it is adding data to the database.